# CSS transition of menu height on show/collapse event

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, css-transitions

I am working on horizontal navbar with collapsible menu. I am using **bootstrap 4** and **angular**. Collapsing/showing is working fine on menu icon click, but I want to bind some CSS transitions (**changing height slowly**). My simple code is here:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SOME BRAND</a>
  <button id="toggler" class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" (click)="toogle();" data-target="#menu" aria-controls="menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>    
  <div class="navbar-collapse" id="menu" [ngClass]="activeClass ? 'show' : 'collapse'" data-parent="#toggler">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

My CSS is:

```
.on-slide-down {
    height: 500px;
}
#menu {
    transition: height 1.5s ease;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And JS function is:

```
toogle(){
    this.activeClass = !this.activeClass;
    let menu:HTMLElement = document.querySelector("#menu");
    menu.classList.toggle("on-slide-down");
  }
```

So my idea is to dynamically bind the class .on-slide-down which increase height. Unfortunately, the transitions is not working. Collapsing and showing the menu has still it's default behaviour. I was doing it according this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/catharsis/n5XfG/17/), but I dont know where is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just override the normal Bootstrap collapse transition? This way you don't need the extra JS:

https://www.codeply.com/go/WJmJoNIlbA

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SOME BRAND</a>
    <button id="toggler" class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu" aria-controls="menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="menu" data-parent="#toggler">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
#menu {
    transition: height 1.5s ease;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your example is working on the link, but in my project is not working. I just copied your code and did not changed anything. Is it possible, that I have to install something into my angular project? It is strange...